# NSwag's AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor marks all endpoints as requiring Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, nswag

I have custom authorization scheme set up like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication("ClientApp")
                .AddScheme<ClientAppAuthenticationOptions, ClientAppAuthenticationHandler>("ClientApp", null);
```

Then I have the following NSwag OpenAPI document config:

```cs
services.AddOpenApiDocument((settings, provider) =>
            {
                settings.DocumentName = "openapi";
                settings.AddSecurity("ClientApp", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Description = "Authentications used for client apps, such as Mmcc.Stats.TpsMonitor",
                    Name = "X-Auth-Token",
                    In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header
                });

                settings.OperationProcessors.Add(
                    new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("ClientApp")
                );
                // ...
            }
```

I've decorated actions in my controllers with `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ClientApp")]`, however NSwag marks all of my endpoints as requring the `ClientApp` authorization in the ReDoc UI with no regard for the decorators. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by changing my code to this:

```cs
settings.DocumentProcessors.Add(
                    new SecurityDefinitionAppender("ClientApp",
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                            Description = "Authentications used for client apps, such as Mmcc.Stats.TpsMonitor",
                            Name = "X-Auth-Token",
                            In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header
                        }));
                settings.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("ClientApp"));
```

Comment: Checkout the code: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore/Processors/AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor.cs#L47

Comment: Had the same issue, did not work with `.AddSecurity` but worked with manually adding the `SecurityDefinitionAppender` to the `DocumentProcessors` as shown above

Comment: Very strange, looks like `.AddSecurity` is just a wrapper for `settings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender(name, globalScopeNames, swaggerSecurityScheme));` yet something is not working when using it directly. 
Maybe I'm not using it the right way or I'm messing up something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right method with `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` that add authentication to global scope.

[image]

```cs
configure.AddSecurity("App-Id", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "AppId needed to access the endpoints",
    Name = "App-Id",
    In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
});
```